# Adding a google map to a metabox, map has inline style height=0

Tags: plugins, google-maps

I've read through a few posts here on stack exchange and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here's my metabox callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function initMap() {
            var mapOpts = {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 14,
                center: { lat: 38.61687, lng: -90.219727 },
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOpts);

        }//end initMap

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            console.log("Map Resized");
        });

        //38.61687,-90.219727
    </script>   

    <table width="100%" class="widefat">

    <tr>    
        <th scope="row"><label for="_latitude">Latitude:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="_latitude" value="<?php print get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_latitude', true ); ?>" /> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><label for="_longitude">Longitude:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="_longitude" value="<?php print get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_longitude', true ); ?>" /></td>      
    </tr>

    </table>

    <h2>Map Below</h2>

    <div style="height:400px;width:800px;"><div id="map-canvas" width="100%" height="100%"></div></div>
```

I read somewhere that the map may be loading before the metabox is created. So I added the maps.event.trigger which shows in the console in firebug, map is undefined/not defined. My console.log function doesn't show in the console either.

I know I must be missing something really small. Google API is loading into the the page via an enqueue scripts hook. And I am hooking into 'add_meta_boxes' action to add my metabox.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT ---------------------------------------------------------

I solved this by adding:

```
#map-canvas {
    height:100%!important;
}
```

to my included css file.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add

```
#map-canvas {
    height:100%!;
}
```

to my stylesheet.